# SQL to sum a total of a column where 2 columns match in a different table

Tags: sql

SO I have 2 tables and would like to SUM the total of a column in one table where 2 other columns match in another table.

In `table1` I have `acc_ref` and `bill_no`.
`acc_ref` is different but `bill_no` could be 1-10 (so 2 or more `acc_ref` could have the same `bill_no`)

In `table2` I have `acc_ref`, `bill_no` and `tran_amnt`. 
Εach `acc_ref` has multiple rows and I want to SUM the `tran_amnt` but only if `acc_ref` and `bill_no` both match in `table1`.

I tried this but I get an error

> 'The columns in the SELECT clause must be contained in the GROUP BY
>   clause'

```
select a.acc_ref, a.bill_no
from table1 a
where exists (select acc_ref, bill_no, SUM (tran_amount)
from table2 b
where a.acc_ref = b.acc_ref
and a.bill_no = b.bill_no
group by acc_ref)
```

Apologies if this is very basic and obvious but I'm struggling!!

Answer (score 0):

In you description it seems like table1 does not contain any useful information. Because both columns you give also exist in table2. So if nothing else from table1 is needed, you could just remove table1 from the query). Still with your problem you should do a simple join

```
SELECT a.acc_ref, a.bill_no, SUM(b.tran_amount)
FROM table1 a
JOIN table2 b ON b.acc_ref = a.acc_ref AND b.bill_no=a.bill_no
GROUP BY a.acc_ref, a.bill_no
```

Comment: sorry I should have said table1 contains information I pulled from another table so only bill_no with a certain date would be in that table. create table table1 as
select acc_ref, bill_no
from ctnotice
where notice_from >= '01.04.2014'
and notice_from <= '31.03.2015'

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should use case:

**Sample:**

```
SELECT 
  TABEL1.Id, 
  CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT Id FROM TABLE2 WHERE TABLE2.ID = TABLE1.ID)
       THEN 'TRUE' 
       ELSE 'FALSE'
  END AS NewFiled  
FROM TABLE1
```